# When a component can edit properties in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was going through a code and found that

> this.props.formVisibility = false

As one cannot update the properties in react's component, the code shouldnt have work but the execution went without any errors.

**Now I am wondering, On what conditions one is able to edit props in the component?**

Comment: according to react official docs receiver shouldn't update props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have parent - child relationship. where parent's state pass as props to child component then whenever you want to update props you need to update parents state not props in child component. once state get updated this will update to props as well in child component hope so it clear the point

refer : https://gist.github.com/sebkouba/a5ac75153ef8d8827b98